# Why does the ball go through the paddle in Squashball game?

Tags: javascript, html, game-physics

I'm working on yet another squash ball type (paddle hits ball) game using Javascript/HTML and I'm stuck at an issue that seems quite common in other context, but as far as I've looked I've found no good solution for this instance of it. Basically my game (unlike say pong) allows you to move your paddle in any direction. Yet if the paddle moves too fast towards a moving ball, the ball will go through it instead of allowing it to bounce.

I've tried using the velocity of the paddle and the ball to predict the next location of the ball but it still seems

My strategy has come down to tracking the velocity of the paddle and predicting where is it going to be next and then using that for my intersection, to avoid any coordinate gaps lost when moving the paddle to fast.

```
    this.vx = this.x - this.lastX;
    this.vy = this.y - this.lastY;
    // predict next point
    this.nextX = this.x + this.vx;
    this.nextY = this.y + this.vy;
```

Then on my game loop I reverse the velocity if a collision is detected from the point calculation

```
    const { paddle, ball } = this;
    const isBallGoingLeft = Math.sign(ball.vx) === -1;
    const paddleX = isBallGoingLeft ? paddle.nextX + paddle.w : paddle.nextX;
    const nextBallX = isBallGoingLeft ? ball.nextX : ball.nextX + ball.w;
// insersect function found here
// found here: http://paulbourke.net/geometry/pointlineplane/
    if (
      intersect(
        ball.x,
        ball.y,
        nextBallX,
        ball.nextY,
        paddleX,
        paddle.y,
        paddleX,
        paddle.y + paddle.h
      )
    ) {
      ball.x = isBallGoingLeft ? paddleX : paddle.x - ball.w;
      ball.vx = -ball.vx;
    }
```

You can see a full fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/r8f0mxjn/4/

I would like to have the ball bounce when the paddle is coming towards it as well as add increase the velocity of the ball from the velocity of the paddle.